# Excel VBA - How to find the last column with data for each row in a loop

Tags: excel, vba7

I'm trying to create a dynamic concatenation script. Below is an image of a sample of the data:

[image: Data]

The goal is to loop through each row in column A and concatenate the values where the header is "Bundle Child x", separated by ";", and put the concatenated list in column A in the appropriate row. For example, the concatenated list in cell A2 should be: AVS5-OD101-GL;BT022204-GL;BT022204-GL;BT01201-GL;BT01201-GL;BT031141-GL

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub SpecialConcatenate()
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim iCell As Range

Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With Sht

    ' Get the last row of data in column B
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value <> ""), 0).Row
    
    ' Loop through cells in Column A and run concatenation
        For Each iCell In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
        ' Find the last column in current row
             lCol = .Cells(iCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Issue is occurring here
            
        Next iCell
    
End With

End Sub
```

I'm not getting any errors, but lCol is not being identified correctly. I'm watching lCol as the code runs, and it's being set to 7 initially, but it's not updating as the loop goes through each row. 7 is accurate when iCell.Row = 2 and 3, but when iCell = 4, lCol should update to 4 and so on. Any suggestions as to why it's not updating?

Comment: `For Each iCell In Range("A2:A" & lRow)` is missing a `.` before `Range` btw.

Comment: Is your data a table (i.e. created with Ctrl+T)? `.End(xlToLeft).Column` will only get to the rightmost column in the table, not the rightmost populated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TEXTJOIN(delimiter,ignore_empty,text1,...)` function can do everything you need. Just use TEXTJOIN function in cell A2 like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,B2:N2)
```

Comment: Unreal. I spent like 2 hours searching and writing this VBA and this is exactly what I needed the whole time. I even spoke to IT at my company trying to figure the VBA out. Thank you!